# \'Diary\' does not have a primary key and can not be updated

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I am making a diary app with Realm Swift and FSCalendar.
When I press the button to add to Realm, the app crashes and the title message is displayed.
Realm Swift is update 10.2.0.
I am testing it on an actual machine.
I deleted the application of the actual machine and installed it.
Do you know the solution?
Xcode12.2 mac11.0.1

```swift
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class PrimaryData: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var Diary: String = ""
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "Diary"
    }
}
```

```swift
    @IBAction func didTapAddNoteButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let diary = Diary()
        diary.date = date
        
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(diary, update: .modified)
        }
        
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSegueViewController", sender: nil)
        
    }
```

```swift
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class Diary: Object {
    
    @objc dynamic var date: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var context: String = ""
    
    open var primaryKey: String {
        return "date"
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the definition of Diary?

Comment: Why don't you find out what the primary key is for the database?  Why are you returning 'Diary' for the primary key?  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I edited it again.
This is the Diary.

Comment: @ElTomato They are not returning 'Diary' as the primary key in the `PrimaryData` object. That's the name of the property to be used *as* a primary key. It's probably not the *best* choice be we don't know the entire use case. See Realm [Objects](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/objects#primary-key). However, now that the question has been updated it's not clear what `PrimaryData` has to do with it

Comment: The code in the Diary object is not correct. You need to have a primaryKey, in this case `date` *but also* the function that returns what the name of the primary key is - `override static func primaryKey()`. You've included that in the `PrimaryData` object but that function was omitted from the `Diary` object. See the code in my answer as a template

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your Diary object does not have a primary key, so this will fail

```
realm.add(diary, update: .modified)
```

From the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#objects-with-primary-keys)

> If your model class includes a primary key, you can have Realm
> intelligently update or add objects based off of their primary key
> values using Realm().add(_:update:).

To fix, add a primary key to your Diary object

```
class Diary: Object {
   @objc dynamic var _id = UUID().uuidString

   override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
       return "_id"
   }
}
```

Please note that if you're ever going to sync using MongoDB Realm, then you must name your primary key `_id`. See the [documention](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sync/configure-your-data-model#define-a-realm-schema) which states

> To work with Realm Sync, your data model must have a primary key field
> called _id. _id can be of type string, int, or objectId.

Answer (score -1):

**AppDelegate in Migration Code because app not delete when changes in model anythings.**

**Please update pod and re-install**

pod 'ObjectMapper'
pod 'RealmSwift'

**Migration Datababse if changes in Module add or remove Object than schemaVersion increment static**

```
var config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
config.schemaVersion = 5
config.migrationBlock = { migration, oldSchemaVersion in }
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

MVVM Structure

**Create a Notification Model**

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import ObjectMapper


public class NotificationResults:Object,Mappable{
    @objc dynamic var status:Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var message:String = ""
    @objc dynamic var current_page:Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var per_page:Int = 0
    var data  : [String : Any] = [:]
    var notificationData = List<NotificationModel>()
    
    /// Primary Key
    public override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "status" /* you can use like id,staus,message..etc..*/
    }
    /// Init Map
    required convenience public init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }
    /// Mapping
    public func mapping(map: Map) {
        status <- map["status"]
        message <- map["message"]
        current_page <- map["data.current_page"]
        per_page <- map["data.per_page"]
        notificationData <- (map["data.data"], ArrayTransform<NotificationModel>())
        
    }
    
}
class NotificationModel: Object,Mappable {
   @objc dynamic var id:Int = 0
   @objc dynamic var title:String = ""
   @objc dynamic var message:String = ""
   @objc dynamic var datetime:String = ""
   /// Primary Key
   public override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
       return "id"
   }
   /// Init Map
   required convenience public init?(map: Map) {
       self.init()
   }
   /// Mapping
   public func mapping(map: Map) {
       id <- map["id"]
       title <- map["title"]
       message <- map["message"]
       datetime <- map["published_at"]
   }
}
```

Comment: A solution you give has nothing to do with the primary key issue he or she is having.

Comment: @ElTomato yes i know but wrong is Diary is not propar object because object single name of primary key.

Comment: Can you clarify what *object single name of primary key* means? I am not sure this answer has anything to do with the question so maybe an explanation will clarify things?

Comment: @Jay Primary keys must contain UNIQUE values, and cannot contain NULL values. or above question "Diary" is not uniqe primary key. i have define primary key in my answer.

Comment: They are not returning the string "Diary" as a primary key. The primaryKey function returns the name of the objects *property* to be used as a primary key. See the documentation of how [Objects](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/objects#primary-key) primary keys are defined. As long as they populate the Diary property with something before writing, it's correct (not recommended, but correct)